# Inverting 2 conditionals in one function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I'm not sure if this is the best title to describe what I'm looking to achieve, but I essentially have 2 conditionals:

1. `current_file.early?`
2. `required_file.early?`

```
if current_file.early? && !required_file.early? do
...
end

if !current_file.early? && required_file.early? do
...
end
```

I think I've been looking at this too long, but I just want to know if there's an easier way for me to simplify this, as they are essentially the inverse of each other. I know I can do a nested if,

```
current_file.early?
 !required_file.early? && do_something
 required_file.early? && do_something_else
```

but that's not what I'm looking for either. I'm trying to find something a little more elegant if it exists.

Comment: if current.early != required.early do ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a truth table for all the possible conditions as follow:

```
Horizontal: current_file.early?
Vertical: requited_file.early?

        true    false
true    noop    first
false   second  noop
```

So there is actually 3 different outcomes: when first condition is true, when second condition is true, otherwise - no operation (noop).

To make your code clear it would be better to define each condition as separate method with meaningful name.

```rb
def first_cond?
  current_file.early? && !requited_file.early?
end

def second_cond?
  !current_file.early? && requited_file.early?
end

if first_cond?
  # when first condition
elsif second_cond?
  # when second condition
else
  # noop
end
```

And yes, **there is no** shorter nor elegant way to simplify the given pair of conditions (in terms of formal logic and its rules).

Comment: This is ultimately what I ended up doing

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a case statement:

```rb
case [current_file.early?, required_file.early?]
when [true, false]
  "do something"
when [false, true]
  "do anything"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Array.html#method-i-select) the files that are `early?` and compare them to the expected results:

```
early_files = [current_file, required_file].select(&:early?)

if early_files == [current_file]
  # ...
elsif early_files == [required_file]
  # ...
end
```

Other possible outcomes are `early_files == []` (no file is early) and `early_files == [current_file, required_file]` (both files are early).

A `case` statement works, too: (note that the brackets are mandatory)

```
case [current_file, required_file].select(&:early?)
when [current_file]
  # ...
when [required_file]
  # ...
end
```

In both of the above examples, `early?` is only called once per file.